# Webpack how to shim module wrapped in window closure?

Tags: javascript, webpack, shim

I have some 3rd party code that is exported with browser-only intentions. It is wrapped in a self-invoking function that expects `window` to be passed.

```
(function (window) { "use strict";
   window['module'] = {}
})(window);
```

Is there a better name to describe this style module?

I would like to use webpack to `require` or `import` this code.

currently using `webpack@3.5.1` I need this to work in Node.js and ES6 environments.

Comment: This is like only the beginning of your problems. But, there are many options out there like this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by using the `imports-loader` and `exports-loader`

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /MyModule\.js/,
    use: [
      "imports-loader?window=>{}",
      "exports-loader?window.MyModule"
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless the author updates its code to [UMD](http://bob.yexley.net/umd-javascript-that-runs-anywhere/) (or similar) there would be no way for you to `require`/`import` it.

I can't think of a way you could actually make it work without the author's modification.

Although, with the help of [the window package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/window) you could use the following trick :

```
//in a separate file
const Window = require("window");
const window = new Window();
global.window = window; //Try with and without this
require("my_module");
module.exports = window["module_global_variable_name"];
```

But that would only work if the author didn't use any other global variables (eg. `fetch` instead of `window.fetch` would ruin the trick).

Comment: fortunately, it looks like there is no use of `window.` properties

Comment: I think this solution can work. Unfortunately, `require("my_module")` is not returning anything because of no export. I believe there is a webpack config step to include it directly that's missing

Comment: Oh right my bad I completely forgot this, I'll edit this right away

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to trying to require/import from window is to desctructure it after your import declarations. This gives you a importish feel without jumping through hoops.

```
// Normal Imports
import Foo from "Foo";

// Globals from window
const {
  Bar
} = window;
```